# Adding methods to methods in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, backbone.js, methods, syntax

I'm using Backbone, but I feel this is more of a general javascript syntax question.
How can I add a method inside a method (or a function inside a function) and call them by chaining both?

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    method1: function(x){
        method2: function(y){
            return x*y;
        }
    }

    // or perhaps
    method1: function(x){
        {
            method2: function(y){
                x = x*y;
            }
        }
        return x;
    }
});

var mymodel = new myModel();
mymodel.method1(3).method2(5); // outputs 15
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually the chaining is acheived by returning the original object.

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    methodSub: function(x){
        this.x -= x;
        return this;
    },
    methodAdd: function(y){
        this.y += y;
        return this;
    }
});
```

Or like this: (but then it's essentially another object and should be defined appropriately)

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    methodSub: function(x){
        this.x -= x;
        return {
             x : this.x,
/*           val : this.x, Or simply val, if that seems appropriate */
             methodAdd: function(y){
                this.x += y;
                return this;
             }
        }
    }
});
```

Don't know if any of them is the way you imagined. But in essence, you have to return something to chain something. Else the method will return **undefined** and you can't call a method "on" **undefined**.

Comment: Not really. When I call `method1` alone, it cannot return `this`. I need `method1` to know wether `method2` is chained after it.

Comment: Dont think you can "know" if a method is chained after or not. But you could so something like (ill change the answer)

Comment: That works great! But how can I return `x` when just calling `mymodel.methodSub(3)`?

Comment: Dont know if theres a better way but you can add x : x in the map I guess. Ill update

Comment: I'm not having any success with that :/